# How to close command window automatically after the batch file had ran

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script in which I call another batch file upon which it calls another batch file. After running this batch file, command prompt which opened is not getting closed.

"call ran.bat" in first batch file.

"start XXX.bat exit" in second batch file.

XXX.bat after running this, it is not getting closed automatically after finishing, each time I have to manually enter "exit" command to close the window.

How to automatically close the window?

Comment: Use `start cmd.exe /C XXX.bat`

Comment: Use `call` to run another batch file rather than `start`...